# Git push error in Rstudio: Cannot spawn SSH: No such file or directory

Tags: r, github

I am trying to be able to use Rstudio for my github repo.

However, when I try to push from Rstudio, I get the error:
Cannot spawn SSH: No such file or directory.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to reinstall the Git.

Comment: Can you use git from outside Rstudio?

Comment: Yes, I am able to change the repo from a shell, just not from Rstudio. Resintalling the git didn't work, but thanks for the suggestion